# how to share both text and Image to whatsapp directltly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need to `share` both `image` and `text` directly to the  `WhatsApp`. I tried with `actionsheet` and `UIDocumentIntractionController`.

I tried with this code:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://app"]]){
 [AdDetailsViewController processImageDataWithURLString:self.strThumbImage andBlock:^(NSData *imageData) {

            self.watsappShareimg = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData];

         }];
        UIImage     * iconImage = self.watsappShareimg; //[UIImage imageNamed:@"flag.png"];
        NSString    * savePath  = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai"];

        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(iconImage, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

        self.documentationInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
        self.documentationInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
        self.documentationInteractionController.delegate = self;

        [self.documentationInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:self.view animated: YES];


    } else {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WhatsApp not installed." message:@"Your device has no WhatsApp installed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Thank u in advance

Comment: According to my experience, we can't post image and text both at the same time to what's app. You can add the text to image and then share it.

Comment: is not possible to share on both

Comment: @minkle if i click one button can i move directly to the whatsapp?is it possible

Comment: @anbu is it possible to share an image directly to whatsapp?

Comment: ya posiible we can send directly option is like we can send Image only or text+ URL Only

Comment: see this image for share image https://ioscoderhub.wordpress.com/2014/05/01/how-can-i-share-image-from-iphone-application-to-whatsapp-line-wechat-programmatically/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UIActivityViewController` to share `image` , `text` or `URL` .This is Apple By default share Method

```
NSString *shareText = @"This is Sharable text";
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Test.png"];

NSArray *array_Object = @[shareText, image];

UIActivityViewController *obj_activity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:array_Object applicationActivities:nil];


[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil]
```

You can try above Code But https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013
On This `Link` They have `Mentioned` that only Independent text is shared. For `Image` ,`audio` ,`Video` use `DocumentationController`.

Comment: The `UIDocumentInteractionController` allows you to send an image, but without text.